# Listbox content in another application

Tags: delphi, winapi, listbox, delphi-7, listboxitems

How can i read a listbox items in another application's window? I could get the window's handle but i dont know a clear way to access components within.

Comment: You are going to need to use VirtualAlloc to allocate memory in the target process. Then send the windows message to get the item text. The read it into your process with ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: @David, I didn't have a problem on my Windows 7 machine with the code from my deleted post (both apps were Delphi and ran with the same elevation of course).

Comment: @TLama Hmm, I'm probably wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to get something from the following project, where is shown, how to enumerate child windows, filter them for a given class name and how to get the items of a list box. I would comment it, but this would be a long story, so please ***take it as a temporary post***...

***Unit1.pas***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TEnumData = class
    ClassName: string;
    HandleItems: TStrings;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CloneListBox: TListBox;
    HandleEdit: TEdit;
    HandleListBox: TListBox;
    HandleEnumButton: TButton;
    procedure HandleEnumButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure HandleListBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function EnumCallback(Handle: HWND; EnumData: TEnumData): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Buffer: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  if GetClassName(Handle, Buffer, 256) <> 0 then
    if Buffer = EnumData.ClassName then
      EnumData.HandleItems.Add(IntToStr(Handle));
end;

procedure GetListBoxItems(Handle: HWND; Target: TListBox);
var
  I: Integer;
  ItemCount: Integer;
  TextBuffer: string;
  TextLength: Integer;
begin
  ItemCount := SendMessage(Handle, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
  if ItemCount <> LB_ERR then
  begin
    Target.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      Target.Clear;
      for I := 0 to ItemCount - 1 do
      begin
        TextLength := SendMessage(Handle, LB_GETTEXTLEN, I, 0);
        SetLength(TextBuffer, TextLength);
        SendMessage(Handle, LB_GETTEXT, I, LPARAM(PChar(TextBuffer)));
        Target.Items.Add(TextBuffer);
      end;
    finally
      Target.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleEnumButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  EnumData: TEnumData;
begin
  EnumData := TEnumData.Create;
  try
    EnumData.ClassName := 'TListBox';
    EnumData.HandleItems := HandleListBox.Items;
    EnumChildWindows(StrToInt(HandleEdit.Text), @EnumCallback, LPARAM(EnumData));
  finally
    EnumData.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleListBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceHandle: Integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(HandleListBox.Items[HandleListBox.ItemIndex], SourceHandle) then
    GetListBoxItems(SourceHandle, CloneListBox);
end;

end.
```

***Unit1.dfm***

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 259
  ClientWidth = 460
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object CloneListBox: TListBox
    Left = 224
    Top = 8
    Width = 228
    Height = 243
    ItemHeight = 13
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object HandleEnumButton: TButton
    Left = 127
    Top = 8
    Width = 88
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Enumerate'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = HandleEnumButtonClick
  end
  object HandleListBox: TListBox
    Left = 8
    Top = 40
    Width = 207
    Height = 211
    ItemHeight = 13
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = HandleListBoxClick
  end
  object HandleEdit: TEdit
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 113
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = '0'
  end
end
```

***Project1.dpr***

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

Get list of child controls with EnumChildWindows (when main window handle is already known).

Then look at the LB_GETTEXT Message on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or Delphi WinSDK Help). Don't forget to check for string length (LB_GETTEXTLEN) and allocate memory buffer

Comment: how can I get components (for example that Listbox) handle?

Comment: why do you think there are components ? That may not be Delphi at all. Or Delphi compiled with different compilation options. Or different Delphi/VCL version. In all those cases you may think those are not components at all. The only thing for sure - that is Windows. So - Windows methods would certainly work (unless bugs). All the rest are wishful thinking. You think "i create Windows listbox with TListBox component, hence every ever created listbox was done with exactly my version of TListBox component". Not so at all.

Comment: The only thing i get with EnumChildWindows is a component named "TspSkinAnimateGauge", I tested EnumChildWindows on my own program and it worked fine but did not work on target program as i want. where is problem?

Comment: why do you think there is a component ? maybe there is only a listbox and nothign to be found.

Comment: And maybe there is no listbox at all, so you can scream `LB_` messages at it all you want, but it will not respond.... :) try spy++ to confirm that's a listbox and not some other animal.

Comment: so, if this is not a component there is no way to read content? and what about i get with EnumChildWindows? what is "TspSkinAnimateGauge"? this is a component or not? if is, program's made by 1 component? im really confused now...

Comment: It's like kobik says. Either you have a control that responds to the messages by the Windows rules or not. You can write, I don't know, a combo box that will respond to edit messages and as a bonus, in a totally different way.

Comment: i used "WinDowse" program, it returned class name as "TspSkinList" and also could get access to everything else on form: TspSkinMemo, TspSkinButton, ....

Comment: If you don't have source code of the controls from your target application then you can only hope they will properly respond to the messages by the Windows rules. Nothing more or less. Try it and if you're lucky, it will work...

Comment: The `Tspxxx` is part of DynamicSkinForm VCL library (it's Delphi). use the handle you get of the `TspSkinList` control.

Comment: handle in every run will change, if i use the handle i get via WinDowse i can not use it next time or in every machine!!

Comment: Then there may be security isolation like UAC or different user launched the program or whatever

Comment: @Armin Of course the handle changes. Use EnumChildWindows like you have been told.

Comment: Then you have to get how does Spy++ or WinDowse get those handles.
Either it traverses tree via set of EnumChildWindows calls, or tries mouse hit test, somethign like GetControlAtPoint - don;t recall exact name but you may look how VCL function is implemented

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/find-vcl-window.htm
Digging around this implementation would probably show you Windows function for it. But EnumChildWindows is still much more reliable. Just you'd maybe would need nested calls, if window is not 2D flat