# LVM_GETITEMPOSITION

Tags: delphi, dll, icons, desktop, inject

iam trying to set/get desktop icons positions, using LVM_GETITEMPOSITION. setting position works as expected, but getting them is not.

when i sendmessage(DeskHandle, LVM_GETITEMPOSITION, 1, ppt); explorer crashes, and thats obviously because ppt is only valid adress in my process, so i need to inject a dll into explorer's memory adress space.. and thats where i'am stuck again

the problem is returned position is always 0,0

dll :

```
library Project2_dll;

uses
  SysUtils,Classes,windows,messages,dialogs,commctrl;

{$R *.res}

procedure hookit; stdcall;
var ppt:tpoint;
    Desktop,DeskHandle : hwnd;
    DeskThread : cardinal;
begin
  Desktop := FindWindow('ProgMan', nil);
  Desktop := FindWindowEx(Desktop, 0, 'SHELLDLL_DefView', nil);
  DeskThread := GetWindowThreadProcessID(Desktop, nil);
  DeskHandle := FindWindowEx(Desktop, 0, 'SysListView32', nil);

  sendmessage(DeskHandle, LVM_GETITEMPOSITION, 1, Longint(@ppt) );
  showmessage(inttostr(ppt.X)+'  '+inttostr(ppt.Y));
end;

exports hookit;

begin

end.
```

exe :

```
var
  lib : hwnd;
  prc: procedure; stdcall;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var hListView : HWND;
    DeskThread : cardinal;
begin
  hListView := FindWindow('ProgMan', nil);
  hListView := FindWindowEx(hListView, 0, 'SHELLDLL_DefView', nil);
  DeskThread := GetWindowThreadProcessID(hListView, nil);

  lib:= LoadLibrary('Project2_dll.dll');
  prc := GetProcAddress(lib, 'hookit');

  HH := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,GetProcAddress(lib, 'getit'),lib,DeskThread);

  prc;
end;
```

i already seen some similar questions here at SO, none was helpful.

ps : running this in Delphi XE, windows 7 x64, and assuming SysListView32 is always a child of progman (not a WorkerW)

any help is appreciated ^_^

Comment: This looks like a global hook attempt, rather than injection. However item getting code does not seem to be related with the hook, not that it would matter. I don't quite grasp what's being tried here.

Comment: @Sertac That message passes a pointer to a struct. That's not marshalled across process boundary. So you need the struct to be in the address space of the target process. Which is where VirtualAllocEx comes in.

Comment: @David - I'm fine with your answer (don't know about the last paragraph). I was trying to understand the code in the question.

Comment: @David, I'd say the only thing you need is 64-bit caller application. There's [`no need`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12071172/960757) to allocate target process memory, I think.

Comment: @TLama In this case there is I believe. Windows doesn't marshal structs across process boundaries. If it did, you'd be fine from the 32 bit process. Note that `LVM_GETITEMPOSITION` expects a pointer to `POINT`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, that looks like a global hook, followed by an in-proc call to `hookit` which causes Explorer to write to an invalid address and die.

Answer (score 4):

You can't inject a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process. In order to inject a DLL into 64 bit explorer you are going to need to get XE2 or XE3 and build a 64 bit DLL. Or write this part of your code in C++ if you do not have access to 64 bit Delphi.

As it happens, your code doesn't inject anyway. It just calls SendMessage from your process. Injection typically involves a call to CreateRemoteThread.

In fact you don't need to inject. You can use `VirtualAllocEx` to allocate memory in the explorer process. You can then pass that address in your `SendMessage`. Since that memory is in the other process, you'll have to use `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` to access it. You will still need to do this from a 64 bit process though.

I would have thought that the shell provides facilities for you to obtain this information without hacking the explorer processes memory.

Comment: so i must compile both 64 and 32, not so~cool :/ but seem only and easiest way
gonna test it anyway..

Comment: It's the only way if you are poking messages at explorer windows. But doesn't the shell offer and interface to this info? Or do the shell designers feel that it's for the interactive user only to decide where their icons should live?